# 'Unsaved Theme' is not appearing when I make a change to a theme in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, themes

According to personal experience and Microsoft documentation, when an aspect of a theme (wallpaper, border colour, etc) is changed in the 'Personalization' screen of Windows 7, a theme called Unsaved Theme is supposed to be created/exist under the 'My Themes' heading.

However, my 'My Themes' section is always empty, and if I change the background by clicking on the Background link at the bottom of the Personalization page, the background changes, but it still shows 'Harmony' as the selected background, and no 'Unsaved Theme' is created. I have no idea how long this has been happening, but I would like to create some themes, but it never acknowledges my changes as it is supposed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had this problem arise today.  To fix, close personalization first. Click startup orb. In search box copy & paste
 %localAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes

Find "Custom.theme" delete to the recycle bin on the safe side.  Now reopen personalization and select any theme.  Change any thing within the theme for example change the screen saver.  Once applied The "Unsaved Theme"  should now appear.  Also you should see that the "Custom.theme" item has been recreated.  Once you fully tested everything to your satisfaction, you can delete the old "Custom.theme" from the recycle bin.